# How to fix fragmentTransaction.replace error and cannot be converted to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am learning Android from a couple of weeks.

I am now trying to use fragments. And using the ideas from https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid
from book
https://books.google.com/books?id=qkzrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=pure+java+class+fragments&source=bl&ots=Ayz-JbqS4r&sig=f2DBRNgX_wrvBnGrDhJiIfHNhrE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD6OHS67rPAhUG1CYKHczIBnAQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=pure%20java%20class%20fragments&f=false

I am getting

> 'replace(int, android.app.fragment)' in
>   'android.app.fragmentTransaction' cannot be applied to

which is also

> Error: ContactDetailFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

source code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


    public class ContactActivity extends Activity implements ContactListFragment.ContactListListener{



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);


        }

        @Override
        public void itemClicked(long id){
            //method also defined in the listener
            View fragmentContainer = findViewById(R.id.fragment_detail_container);
            if (fragmentContainer != null){
                ContactDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new ContactDetailsFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                detailsFragment.setContact(id);
                //fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_detail_container, detailsFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_detail_container, detailsFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }

        }

    }
```

contactactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context="esu.uco.rawal.p5rabina.ContactActivity">
        <fragment
            class="esu.uco.rawal.p5rabina.ContactListFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight ="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/contact_list_frag"/>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: R.id.fragment_detail_container Is it container or view? Can you add xml file layout where you want to add this fragment?

Comment: @EEJ its container. i have added xml layout. please check it.

Comment: Sounds like you've imported the wrong Fragment class or should be using the supportFragmentManager instead

Comment: @cricket_007 i am following the tutorial on that book. I have mentioned above. It don't seem to be supportFragmentManager in that example. i have added more codes. please see and suggest me a solution.

Comment: Yes, that code shows `android.app.Fragment`, however, your IDE might have imported `android.support.v4.Fragment` instead. Check the package import statements

Comment: @cricket_007 it is importing right version. you can check my import statements from the updates.

Comment: The same import used in `ContactDetailFragment`?

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you. just placed android.app.Fragment import statement and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you imports. You may use wrong packages.

There are two Fragment classes:

- [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)
- [v4 Support Library
  Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

as well as two FragmentTransaction classes:

- [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)
- [v4 Support Library FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

You can't use a v4 FragmentTransaction with a native Fragment or the opposite.

You may also want to read the [Support Library Features](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html) docs.